# Concrete Map#empty leading to design smell when creating a custom Map extension

Tags: scala, collections, scala-collections

I am attempting to write a `ForwardingMutableMap` trait, a la [Guava's `ForwardingMap` for Java](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ForwardingMap.html).

Here's what my fist attempt looked like:

```
trait ForwardingMutableMap[K, V, +Self <: mutable.MapLike[K, V, Self] with mutable.Map[K, V]] 
    extends mutable.Map[K, V] 
    with mutable.MapLike[K, V, Self] { this: Self =>

  protected val delegate: mutable.Map[K, V]

  def get(key: K): Option[V] = delegate.get(key)

  def iterator: Iterator[(K, V)] = delegate.iterator

  def -=(key: K): this.type = {
    delegate -= key
    this
  }

  def +=(kv: (K, V)): this.type = {
    delegate += kv
    this
  }
}
```

This leads to the error:

```
error: overriding method empty in trait MapLike of type => Self;
 method empty in trait Map of type => scala.collection.mutable.Map[K,V] has incompatible type
       trait ForwardingMutableMap[K, V, +Self <: mutable.MapLike[K, V, Self] with mutable.Map[K, V]]
```

Second attempt:

```
trait ForwardingMutableMap[K, V, +Self <: mutable.MapLike[K, V, Self] with mutable.Map[K, V]] 
    extends mutable.Map[K, V] 
    with mutable.MapLike[K, V, Self] { this: Self =>

  def empty: Self

  protected val delegate: mutable.Map[K, V]

  def get(key: K): Option[V] = delegate.get(key)

  def iterator: Iterator[(K, V)] = delegate.iterator

  def -=(key: K): this.type = {
    delegate -= key
    this
  }

  def +=(kv: (K, V)): this.type = {
    delegate += kv
    this
  }
}
```

Error:

```
error: overriding method empty in trait ForwardingMutableMap of type => ForwardingMutableMap.this.Self;
 method empty in trait Map of type => scala.collection.mutable.Map[K,V] has incompatible type;
 (Note that method empty in trait ForwardingMutableMap of type => ForwardingMutableMap.this.Self is abstract,
  and is therefore overridden by concrete method empty in trait Map of type => scala.collection.mutable.Map[K,V])
       trait ForwardingMutableMap[K, V, +Self <: mutable.MapLike[K, V, Self] with mutable.Map[K, V]]
```

Third attempt:

```
trait ForwardingMutableMap[K, V, +Self <: mutable.MapLike[K, V, Self] with mutable.Map[K, V]] 
    extends mutable.Map[K, V] 
    with mutable.MapLike[K, V, Self] { this: Self =>

  override def empty: Self = empty2

  def empty2: Self

  protected val delegate: mutable.Map[K, V]

  def get(key: K): Option[V] = delegate.get(key)

  def iterator: Iterator[(K, V)] = delegate.iterator

  def -=(key: K): this.type = {
    delegate -= key
    this
  }

  def +=(kv: (K, V)): this.type = {
    delegate += kv
    this
  }
}
```

The types mixing `ForwardingMutableMap` will have to implement `empty2` instead of `empty`.

This works but smells of a hack. Can I do better?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is already implemented in Scala standard library, which named `MapProxy`. Here is the source code :[src](https://github.com/scala/scala/tree/e67a039ec2/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/MapProxy.scala#L1)

```
scala> new mutable.MapProxy[Int, Int]{ override val self = HashMap.empty[Int, Int] }
res1: scala.collection.mutable.MapProxy[Int,Int]{val self: scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[Int,Int]} = Map()

scala> res1 += ((1,2))
res2: <refinement>.type = Map(1 -> 2)

scala> res1
res3: scala.collection.mutable.MapProxy[Int,Int]{val self: scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[Int,Int]} = Map(1 -> 2)
```

Comment: The documentation for MapProxy currently says "Deprecated:  (Since version 2.11.3) Proxying is deprecated due to lack of use and compiler-level support."

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
trait ForwardingMutableMap[K, V]
  extends Map[K, V] with MapLike[K, V, ForwardingMutableMap[K, V]] {

  override def empty = ForwardingMutableMap.empty

  protected val delegate: Map[K, V]

  def get(key: K): Option[V] = delegate.get(key)

  def iterator: Iterator[(K, V)] = delegate.iterator

  def -=(key: K): this.type = {
    delegate -= key
    this
  }

  def +=(kv: (K, V)): this.type = {
    delegate += kv
    this
  }
}

object ForwardingMutableMap {
  def empty[K, V]:ForwardingMutableMap[K, V] = new ForwardingMutableMap[K, V] {
    protected val delegate = Map.empty[K, V]
  }
}
```

---

### Edit

If you don't want it to be concrete, but a trait similar to `MapLike` (which can have multiple concrete implementations) you can define it like this:

```
trait ForwardingMutableMap[K, V, Self <: ForwardingMutableMap[K, V, Self] with Map[K, V]]
  extends MapLike[K, V, Self] { 

  protected val delegate: Map[K, V]

  // ...
}
```

And then use it like this

```
class MyMap[K, V](val delegate:Map[K, V]) extends Map[K, V] with ForwardingMutableMap[K, V, MyMap[K, V]] {
  override def empty = MyMap.empty
}

object MyMap {
  def empty[K, V] = new MyMap[K, V](Map.empty) 
}
```

Comment: Why do you need `Self`? In `MapLike` it is defined on order to have a reference to the self type. More information about this construct can be found here: [Selfreferencing Generics](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/14939893/selfreferencing-generics)

Comment: I understand, you want to it to be similar to `MapLike`.

Comment: I changed my answer, I hope this answers the "Where's my `Self`?" question of your previous comment.

Comment: Looks good. Thanks. Will re-look at this later and revert if I have any further questions.